# Flutter error: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter

There was a problem after updating `pubspec.yaml`:

[image: error message]

> error: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

Comment: add the code in written form instead of screenshots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The method '\[\]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575893/the-method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-the-receiver-can-be-nu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The method \[\] can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73822190/the-method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-the-receiver-can-be-null)

Answer (score 0):

check if value != null or if you are sure it is not null add '!' to the of it